# Using F for FALSE sometimes fails

Tags: r

I just noticed that I now have to explicitly state `FALSE` when using such functions as `read.csv` or setting `printFlag` to `FALSE` in `mice`. Is this an update to RStudio or just a bug?

Sample:

```
read.csv(text="1,S0006,C000124,12Jan2017,179,7296
2,S0002,C000124,26Feb2017,109,7941
         3,S0008,C000124,22Feb2017,190,4511
         4,S0006,C000124,03Jan2017,150,7296
         5,S0005,C000124,08Feb2017,120,5812
         6,S0003,C000124,26Apr2017,46,7512",header=F)
```

fails with:

> Error in !header : invalid argument type
>   which can then be fixed by setting `header=FALSE`

```
RStudio: $version
[1] ‘1.1.463’
R: 3.5.3RC
```

Comment: In R 3.5.2 in visual studio, it works ok

Comment: Works in R 3.5.1, RStudio Version 1.1.456

Comment: Did you try with `header = FALSE` and it actually works?

Comment: try `print(F)`: you might have another value assigned to `F`?

Comment: Yes, it works with `header=FALSE`.

Comment: Works for me in R3.5.3, Rstudio 1.1.456

Comment: Try restarting R.

Comment: @BenBolker right, I attempted answering some question that had a variable set to `F`. Variable names!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can *almost* replicate this (not quite the same error message) by assigning a character value to `F`:

```
F <- "abc"
read.csv(text="1,S0006,C000124,12Jan2017,179,7296
    2,S0002,C000124,26Feb2017,109,7941
          3,S0008,C000124,22Feb2017,190,4511
          4,S0006,C000124,03Jan2017,150,7296
          5,S0005,C000124,08Feb2017,120,5812
          6,S0003,C000124,26Apr2017,46,7512",header=F)
```

> Error in !header : invalid argument type

using `FALSE` instead of `F` is a good idea (for precisely this reason); you could also try `rm(F)` and see if that allows your original code to work.

Comment: I'm guessing that this probably exactly replicates the error; but OP forgot to insert a line break in the question between this message and the following words.